# See events from my application together with dissected communication in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I sometimes need to use Wireshark to analyze communication issues with a particular protocol that my application uses. Wireshark already comes with a dissector for the protocol, and displays the communication in the best possible way I can imagine.

But I also need to view the actual communication together with events happening inside my application. The application is capable of generating various logs and traces. The information in them is actually more structured, but for the simplicity, let's say it is just a sequence of entries where each entry has a timestamp and a textual message.

Currently, I have to place the Wireshark and the logs alongside on the screen, and painfully correlate the timestamps in order to figure out how they belong together. In order to make my analysis much easier, I would like to view the information from my logs merged together with the communication protocol messages in Wireshark, properly sorted by their timestamps.

I found that Wireshark has a Merge capability, so this is where I am directing my investigation. I think that with some effort, I might be able to do the following:
1) Design my own "protocol", and generate PCAPNG file from my application, with the event timestamps and messages, and
2) Developer a Wireshark dissector for the above, so that I can view the events in Wireshark.

The first part of my question is whether my approach is the right one.

But I also wonder whether I cannot achieve what I want in some simpler way. Ideally, I would like to reuse something that already exists, and specifically, avoid developing a specialized dissector. Isn't there a protocol with identical features (just timestamps and textual messages), with a dissector that Wireshark already has, that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could make use of [syslog](https://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) along with [syslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd) or [rsyslogd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd)?

One way to inject arbitrary messages into trace files without even having a syslog server is to make use of [nc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) (netcat).  For example:

```
echo -n "Hello World" | nc -w 0 -u 1.1.1.1 514
```

Wireshark will also dissect this message as syslog traffic.  This can be useful when trying to insert "markers" into capture files near where an event of interest occurs.

In any case, making use of syslog facilities would save you from having to write your protocol.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something even simpler than syslog (just timestamp and text). But there probably isn't such a thing already available, and therefore the syslog looks like the best choice - also given the amount of extra tools (some of which you have listed) to help with it. I forgot to mention in my question that I work on Windows and not all of tools are (or are fully) available, but still the syslog is the winner. If Wireshark attempts to dissect, by default, anything on port 514 as syslog even if not conforming to the protocol, and shows it as text, it would be perfect then.